# Login button is not working while pressing enter in a pop up window form in chrome extension

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension, popupwindow

Hi I have created a pop up window containing a form asking the user to enter email and password.And there is a log in button.Usually in most of the forms, after entering all details and pressing 'enter', the submit button will be automatically clicked.But in this case,only when I click the login button it works.I want it to work on pressing 'enter' in keyboard.I know that this is a simple question.But I can't figure it out why is this happening.Please help me
Here is my userinfo.html(pop up window)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>       
</head>
<body>
<b>Enter your Email ID and Password</b><br><br>
    <form id="userinfo">
        <label for="user">&nbsp;Email&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="text" id="user" /><span id="semail"></span>
        <br><br>
       <label for="pass">Password&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
       <input type="password" id="pass" />
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="button" id="login" value="Log In"/>
      </form>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Here is my test.js

```
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var user  = document.querySelector('input#user');
     var pwd  = document.querySelector('input#pass');
     var login = document.querySelector('input#login');

     login.addEventListener('click', function() {     

     var userStr = user.value; 
     var pwdStr = pwd.value;

    chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(bgPage) {
     bgPage.login(userStr,pwdStr); });
     window.close();


     }); 

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for a *submit* event to be triggered on `ENTER` the form must have a *submit* button.
In your particular case, you need to revent the default behaviour of your form, since you want to handle it "manually" using the background-page.

In summary, the following steps are required:

- Change the button type from `button` to `submit`.
- Register a listener for the form's *submit* event. (Note: this will be triggered on both *button-click* and *ENTER*.)
- Prevent the default behaviour on form-submit.
- Delegate the login-handling to the background-page (through its `login` method.

**Here is the new code:**

*test.html*

```
<h4>Enter your Email ID and Password</h4>
<form id="userinfo">
    <label for="user">E-mail:    </label>
    <input type="text" id="user" required />
    <br />
    <label for="pass">Password:  </label>
    <input type="password" id="pass" required />
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" id="login" value="Log In" />
</form>
```

*test.js*

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var form = document.querySelector('form#userinfo');
    var user = document.querySelector('input#user');
    var pass = document.querySelector('input#pass');

    /* Register a listener on the form's `submit` event */
    form.addEventListener('submit', function (evt) {
        /* Prevent the event from being handled by the browser */
        evt.preventDefault();

        var userStr = user.value;
        var passStr = pass.value;

        /* Delegate login-handling to background-page */
        chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function (bgPage) {
            bgPage.login(userStr, passStr);
        });
        window.close();
    });
});
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/Rk76y/)**.

Comment: hey I have posted another question.Will you please refer this link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20367833/how-to-close-a-notification-window-automatically-based-on-browser-action    please help me