# How to close a notification window automatically

Tags: google-chrome-extension, notifications

Hi I am displaying a notification based on the output of a server file.The output of the server file is being checked for a period of 5 min interval.Now what I need is that when the output changes at any instant, notification should be automatically be closed at that moment.What I am trying to convey that if the output of the server file is 0,the notification is being displayed in every 5 min. If the output is 1, then notification will not be shown anymore.The problem of my code is that unless I close the notification manually it won't be closed automatically even if the output is 1. Anyone please help me to close my notification automatically.
here is my background.js

```
var myNotificationID = null;
var oldChromeVersion = !chrome.runtime;
function getGmailUrl() {
 return "http://calpinemate.com/";
  }


 function isGmailUrl(url) { 
return url.indexOf(getGmailUrl()) == 0;

 }

 chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
 if(!localStorage.username){
 chrome.windows.create({url : "userinfo.html",type: "popup", height: 200, width:300 , top :400 , left : 800}); 


    }
    else{
      chrome.tabs.query({

    url: "http://calpinemate.com/*",

   currentWindow: true
    },
    function(tabs) {

    if (tabs.length > 0) {

       var tab = tabs[0];

       console.log("Found (at least one) Gmail tab: " + tab.url);

       console.log("Focusing and refreshing count...");

       chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { active: true });

       updateIcon();

        }
      else {

       console.log("Could not find Gmail tab. Creating one...");

       chrome.tabs.create({ url: getGmailUrl() });

       updateIcon();

        }
         });
            }
      });



     function onInit() {

       console.log('onInit');

       updateIcon();

         if (!oldChromeVersion) {

         chrome.alarms.create('watchdog', {periodInMinutes:5});

           }

             }




      function onAlarm(alarm) {

         console.log('Got alarm', alarm);

         if (alarm && alarm.name == 'watchdog') {

            onWatchdog();

             } 
          else {

         updateIcon();

           }

          }




      function onWatchdog() {

        chrome.alarms.get('refresh', function(alarm) {

           if (alarm) {

           console.log('Refresh alarm exists. Yay.');

              } 
          else {
       console.log('Refresh alarm doesn\'t exist!? ' +
              'Refreshing now and rescheduling.');

        updateIcon();

           }
          });

          }


      if (oldChromeVersion) {

        updateIcon();

           onInit();

             } 

            else {

       chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(onInit);

       chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(onAlarm);

         }




   function updateIcon(){

    var urlPrefix = 'http://www.calpinemate.com/employees/attendanceStatus/';
    var urlSuffix = '/2';

       var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

      req.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {

     if (req.readyState == 4) {

       if (req.status == 200) {  
       var item=req.responseText;
       if(item==1){
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"calpine_logged_in.png"});
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color:[190, 190, 190, 230]});
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:""});  
        chrome.notifications.clear(id1);//this is not working

         }

      else{
       chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"calpine_not_logged_in.png"});   
       chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color:[190, 190, 190, 230]});           
       chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:""}); 
        chrome.notifications.create(
       'id1',{
       type: 'basic',
       iconUrl: '/calpine_not_logged_in.png',
       title: 'Warning : Attendance',
        message: 'Please mark your Attendance !',
       buttons: [{ title: 'Mark',
                        iconUrl: '/tick.jpg'
                  },{ title: 'Ignore',
                        iconUrl: '/cross.jpg'}],
       priority: 0},
       function(id) { myNotificationID = id;}
      );


  chrome.notifications.onButtonClicked.addListener(function(notifId, btnIdx) {
  if (notifId === myNotificationID) {
    if (btnIdx === 0) {
        window.open("http://www.calpinemate.com/");
    } else if (btnIdx === 1) {
       notification.close();
    }
    }
   });

 chrome.notifications.onClosed.addListener(function() {
  notification.close();
 });


 }

      } 
   else {

        // Handle the error

        alert("ERROR: status code " + req.status);

       }

       }

    });
    var url = urlPrefix + encodeURIComponent(localStorage.username) + urlSuffix;
    req.open("GET", url);

   req.send(null);

   }
```

Comment: Hi I hope I have to use chrome.notifications.clear or chrome.notifications.getAll() to removw the notification.But can anyone give syntax of either??please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Two possible problems:

1. You pass an undefined variable named `id1` in `chrome.notifications.clear()`, when you actually mean the string `'id1'`.
2. According to the docs on **[`chrome.notifications.clear()`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications.html#method-clear)** method, the second argument (callback function) is not optional, yet you fail to supply one.

#### One possible solution:

```
// Replace that line:
chrome.notifications.clear(id1);//this is not working

// With this line:
chrome.notifications.clear('id1', function(){});//this is working perfectly

// Or with this line:
chrome.notifications.clear(myNotificationID, function(){});//this is working perfectly
```

---

BTW, you don't need to provide a notification ID yourself.
You can replace: `chrome.notifications.create('id1',...`
with: `chrome.notifications.create('',...`
<sub>(and then, of course, use: `chrome.notifications.clear(myNotificationID,...`)</sub>